# Inherited routing data does not work in CanActivate guard

Tags: angular

Routing settings: `paramsInheritanceStrategy: 'always'`

Works in 99%. Params and data from higher components are passed to lower. Both are accessible in components in activated route params and data. The problem occurs in CanActivate. Let's say we have such routing:

```
path: '/a',
data: {
  param1: true
},
resolve: {subject: SubjectResolver},
children: [
  {
    path: ':someParammeeero',
    component: B,
    canActivate: [BGuard]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: A
  }
]
```

Component A has a button that redirects to component B. When am in component A I have access to the route.data.subject but when I try to go to component B, inside the BGuard activated route there is no subject inside data but there is param1 so... it's like the inheritance works but not in resolve case. Inside guard I have to access route.parent.data.subject.

When am on component B and refresh the page, all works correctly.

I have two different behaviors inside the guard.

1. When I navigate to the B component I have to access route.parent.data.subject.
2. When being at the B component page I and refresh the page I have to access route.data.subject

Is it a bug or a feture? Maybe my routing structure is incorrent?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the way I was navigating from component A to component B

`this.router.navigate(..., {relatedTo: this.activatedRoute})`

'relatedTo' in some way removed inheritance from /a to /a:someParammeeero